# Efficient way to check sample points on many Landsat scenes?

Tags: landsat-8, accuracy

I want to do an accuracy assessment for an annual burned area map (large area - whole country). I have random sampling points which I need to check in simple burned - not burned categories but throughout the fire season of several months. I have sample points in around 60 Landsat scenes and depending on cloud cover there will hopefully be imagery available from several acquisition dates. Assuming that it will be possible to use 3-4 dates per scene, I need in total at least 180-240 scenes.

Is there an efficient way/online tool/software to look at Landsat-8 scenes in different band combinations without having to download them? Something where I can use my point layer and click through an archive of Landsat data?

I fear I am dreaming of something non-existent...any hints?

Answer (score 1):

[Google Earth Engine](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/) has all the functionality you need to do any of the following of your workflow (and much more):

1. [Visualize imagery](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/)
2. [Generate training data](https://geohackweek.github.io/GoogleEarthEngine/05-classify-imagery/)
3. [Supervised classification](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/classification)
4. [Perform an accuracy assessment](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/classification)

Answer (score 0):

You can try **Snapsat**

reason being: Creating a custom Landsat 8 composite has required that users download the entirety of the scene they were interested in, configure the tools required to process them, and then hope that they produced the intended output. Snapsat was created as a means of simplifying that process. Users are able to rapidly preview scenes and download full-size renders without having to take the time to download or configure anything.

Comment: You haven't linked to "snapsat" and after a little googling I found it and the site does not respond.